# dispatch_time_t output value

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Consider following code:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC));

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Popped after %llu time!", popTime);
    });
```

And it output not 2,5 seconds, but  4445236369163.

How could that be? Dispatch_time_t is just `typedef` for `uint64_t`, which simply an unsigned integer, without sign extension bit.

Even with that weird value, app works just fine, outputing log after 2,5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into documentation, dispatch_time_t is:

```
"A somewhat abstract representation of time."
```

You should not thought about it as a time expressed in second or nanosecond, so there is nothing wrong with your output.

Comment: should we consider that value as "abstract"? What about, if we need a situation when we have to know exactly amount of time? Just curious..

Comment: Then do not use magic constant `2.5`, but store it somewhere and use it in your block as well. Or store actual time just before you call `dispatch_after` and compare it in your block. If you want to learn more about `dispatch_time`, just [check source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/time.c).